# How i change the Enabled= attribute via a preloaded field

Tags: c#

I want to modify the `PXUIField Enabled=false/true` using an existing boolean field

```
public abstract class lastBatNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}

protected String _LastBatNbr;
[PXDBString(10, IsFixed = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Batch Nbr")] 

public virtual String LastBatNbr
{
    get
    {
    return this._LastBatNbr;
    }
    set
    {
    this._LastBatNbr = value;
    }
}
```